# java myeclipse. i am trying to load data from csv file and add all the numbers in 10 column

Tags: java, myeclipse

scanning the csv document using scanner class
i get error at int number= Integer.parseInt(values[9]);
ERROR:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "207""
    at

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at netex.netEx.main(netEx.java:24)

package example;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class myex 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String fileName= "pedestrain.csv";
            File file = new File(fileName);  
            Scanner inputStream;
            try {
                inputStream = new Scanner(file);
                inputStream.next();
                double sum=0;
                double numberOfEntries=0;
                while (inputStream.hasNext())
                {
                    String data= inputStream.next();
                    String values []= data.split(",");                 
                    int number= Integer.parseInt(values[9]);
                    sum = sum + number;     
                    numberOfEntries++;
                }
                inputStream.close();
                System.out.println(sum);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's written in the File you want to read?
It seems like that is no string that's only made out of numbers.

Comment: Identification,Date_Time,Year,Month,Mdate.Day,Time,Sensor_ID, Sensor_Name and  Hourly_Counts  are column names

eg:

1 _01-JUN-2009_00:00 2009 June 1 Monday 0 4 TownHall(West) 194


2 _01-JUN-2009_00:00 2009 June 1 Monday 0 17 CollinsPlace(South) 21

Comment: Please give an example line